# How to add a background theme and/or background wallpaper to my app?

Tags: java, android

How to add a background theme and/or background wallpaper to my app? Right now my app background is plane.

Comment: We need a lot more information. What kind of app? What do you define as "plane" background? And this has nothing to do with eclipse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an XML file in the values directory that contains the style. It could be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="YourTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/your_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

For the case above to work, you need to have an image called `your_background.png` in the drawable folder. Then, you can apply that style to either your whole app or one specific activity by doing this in your manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="bla.bla">
    <application android:theme="@style/YourTheme"> <!-- This is for the whole app  -->

        <activity android:name="bla.bla.YourActivity"
                  android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"/><!-- This is for a specific activity  -->

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: hi Cristian a compilation error at line number 4 in your xml file..saying @drawable is not correctly spelled..

Answer (score 0):

You might be using some layout XML for UI. Set layout (linear, relative, etc) background with any image you want to set your background to. Make sure that the image is available in the `res/drawable` folder.